# Logistics data sources for data analysis work

Tags: geospatial, transportation, public-transport

Where can I find logistics data sets?

I look for data for my student to analyse in a bachelor thesis.

Answer (score 2):

[Transport and Logistics Case Study Data Set (Cargo 2000)](https://www.kaggle.com/crawford/cargo-2000-dataset)

The case study data comprises tracking and tracing events from a forwarding company’s Cargo 2000 system for a period of five months. From those Cargo 2000 messages, we reconstructed execution traces of 3,942 actual business process instances, comprising 7,932 transport legs and 56,082 service invocations. Each execution trace includes planned and effective durations (in minutes) for each of the services of the business process (introduced in Section II), as well as airport codes for the DEP (“departure”) and RCF (“arrival”) services. Due to the fact that handling of transport documents along the business process differs based on whether the documents are paper-based or electronic, we focus on the flow of physical goods, as our data set did not allow us to discern the different document types.

-Transport Tracker Solution | Google Developers
https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/transport-tracker/
-GIS in logistics and vehicle routing applications - Geospatial World
https://www.geospatialworld.net › Articles
-Mapping for Transport & Logistic Professionals | MapData Services
https://mapdataservices.com/industries-transport-logistics
-UCI Machine Learning Repository: Data Sets

Lafifi, Mohamed-Mourad. (2019). Re: Transport and Logistics dataset?. Retrieved from: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Transport_and_Logistics_dataset/5c54a4244f3a3e4b096edf76/citation/download.